# Cut function in R acting strangely

Tags: r

I feel this should be very simple and has always worked in the past. I wrote a simple `cut` function to bin age data into categories:

```
janorgssub$agecat<-cut(as.numeric(janorgssub$Age), breaks = c(0, 1, 5, 25, 50, 65, 130), labels = c('<1','1-5','6-25','26-50','51-65','>65'), include.lowest = TRUE)
```

but it returns funny answers:

```
head(janorgssub$Age)
[1] 32   65   <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
77 Levels:  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 ... NM
head(janorgssub$agecat)
[1] 6-25  51-65 <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> 
Levels: <1 1-5 6-25 26-50 51-65 >65
```

Why is '32' coming out as '6-25'? Many points are correct but seems to randomly assign wrong categories.

(sorry for only two data points and NA's...but returns errors in other places as well).

Comment: I guess you have a factor column . Convert to numeric by `as.numeric(as.character(yourcolumn))` Or `as.numeric(level(yournumeric))`  When you convert a factor to `numeric` directly, you are getting the index of levels of factor.

Comment: Did you intentionally turn your data `janorgssub$Age` into factors?

Comment: THANK YOU. Knew it was something silly. No, didn't intentionally change variables to factors; just imported that way from the csv.